# In a ggplot with multiple paths, how to have one path in a different colour from others (using geom_path())?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table with three columns - subject id, x coordinates and y coordinates. I am able to plot a graph in ggplot where I give colours to the path based on subject id.

```
set.seed(1)

dat<-tibble(id=as.character(rep(c(1,2,3),5)),
            x=runif(15,1,10),
            y=runif(15,1,10))

ggplot(dat,aes(x,y,col=id))+
  geom_path()
```

But the problem arises when I want to make only one subject's path in one colour and the rest of the paths in another colour. So, all the paths except the selected path should be, say black in colour and the selected path should be red in colour.

So I want something like this to work:

```
input<-1

set. Seed(1)

dat<-tibble(id=as.character(rep(c(1,2,3,4),5)),
            x=runif(20,1,10),
            y=runif(20,1,10))

ggplot(dat,aes(x,y,col=ifelse(id==input,"red","black"))+
  geom_path()+
  labs(title = paste("Subject id:",input))
```

I tried creating a column for the colours and then using `scale_colour_manual()`, and also using named vectors for palettes. These should work if my input was static, but I want the `input` object to be given by the user in a shiny app.

I think essentially the problem is that I want ggplot to honour the subject id and split the paths according to the subject id when I assign it to the colour argument, but then I want ggplot to actually colour these paths using a different criteria. I hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood your intention correctly, you want a ggplot with `geom_path`s, referring to an `id` variable, in a shiny app, in which the path of a user-selected `id` is highlighted. The following is an example of how you could start to approach this.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- tibble(
  id = rep(paste("id", 1:4, sep = "_"), 5),
  xx = runif(20, 1, 10),
  yy = runif(20, 1, 10)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("selected_id", "Please select", choices = unique(dat$id)),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dat %>% 
      ggplot(aes(
        xx, 
        yy, 
        group = id, 
        color = if_else(id == input$selected_id, "red", "black")
        )) +
      geom_path() +
      scale_color_identity() +
      labs(
        title = paste(input$selected_id, "is red, all the other id's are black")
      )
  }, res = 96)
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```